# Conditional cbind() on dates

Tags: r, cbind

Assume we have 2 dataframes of 2 cols and 6 rows each and we want to cbind both only when date on the left(lhs) is older than date on the right(rhs), at the same time making sure that each row has no date duplicates (in both lhs and rhs): for instance..

```
x = cbind(data.frame(lhs_date = seq(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(),2)), letter=c("A","B","C","D","E","F") )
Y = cbind(data.frame(rhs_date = seq(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(),1)), letter=c("X","Y","Y","X","J","J") )
```

How can we cbind or left join x to y only when lhs date < rhs date maintaining the uniqueness of each row?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question but are you looking for something like this?

```r
# packages
library(fuzzyjoin)

# data
x <- data.frame(lhs_date = seq(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date(), 2), letter = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
y <- data.frame(rhs_date = seq(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date(), 1), letter = c("X","Y","Y","X","J","J"))

# left join
fuzzy_left_join(
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  by = c("lhs_date" = "rhs_date"),
  match_fun = list(`<`)
)
#>      lhs_date letter.x   rhs_date letter.y
#> 1  2019-11-21        A 2019-11-22        Y
#> 2  2019-11-21        A 2019-11-23        Y
#> 3  2019-11-21        A 2019-11-24        X
#> 4  2019-11-21        A 2019-11-25        J
#> 5  2019-11-21        A 2019-11-26        J
#> 6  2019-11-23        B 2019-11-24        X
#> 7  2019-11-23        B 2019-11-25        J
#> 8  2019-11-23        B 2019-11-26        J
#> 9  2019-11-25        C 2019-11-26        J
#> 10 2019-11-21        D 2019-11-22        Y
#> 11 2019-11-21        D 2019-11-23        Y
#> 12 2019-11-21        D 2019-11-24        X
#> 13 2019-11-21        D 2019-11-25        J
#> 14 2019-11-21        D 2019-11-26        J
#> 15 2019-11-23        E 2019-11-24        X
#> 16 2019-11-23        E 2019-11-25        J
#> 17 2019-11-23        E 2019-11-26        J
#> 18 2019-11-25        F 2019-11-26        J
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that was close but not what I meant. Each row on lhs must be unique as well as each row on rhs. This implies that out of 6 rows we may end up with less or even no rows if any row in lhs is older than rhs. It is basically a cross join between each row of lhs vs each row in rhs returning unique values wit no duplicates. In this case it would be something like this:
2019-11-21        A 2019-11-22        Y
2019-11-23        B 2019-11-24        X
2019-11-25        C 2019-11-26        J
...etc.

Comment: @AlGrasso, I'm still not sure that I understand your comment since I don't get the same output that you describe. Can you check if `bind_cols(x, y) %>% 
  filter(lhs_date >= rhs_date)` works for your example? You need to load the package `dplyr` and define `x` and `y` as I did in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is based on the initial agila input: after fuzzy joining dplyr pipe operator can do the rest:

```
x <- data.frame(lhs_date = seq(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date(), 2), letter = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
y <- data.frame(rhs_date = seq(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date(), 1), letter = c("X","Y","Y","X","J","J"))

z= fuzzy_left_join(
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  by = c("lhs_date" = "rhs_date"),
  match_fun = list(`<`)
)

z %>%
  group_by(lhs_date) %>%
  mutate(flag = row_number()) %>%
  filter(flag ==1)
```

I could easily reproduce in SQL but struggled with R. Thanks @Agila. Although incomplete, your answer pointed to the right direction and went to a long extent

Answer (score 0):

As 'dplyr' has now gained `joined_by` argument in mutating joins, we can now do it in `dplyr`

```r
x = cbind(data.frame(lhs_date = seq(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(),2)), letter=c("A","B","C","D","E","F") )
Y = cbind(data.frame(rhs_date = seq(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(),1)), letter=c("X","Y","Y","X","J","J") )

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

x |>
  left_join(Y, by = join_by(closest(lhs_date < rhs_date)))
#>     lhs_date letter.x   rhs_date letter.y
#> 1 2023-03-24        A 2023-03-25        Y
#> 2 2023-03-26        B 2023-03-27        X
#> 3 2023-03-28        C 2023-03-29        J
#> 4 2023-03-24        D 2023-03-25        Y
#> 5 2023-03-26        E 2023-03-27        X
#> 6 2023-03-28        F 2023-03-29        J
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>